# Valid JSON returns nil in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, binding, null, option-type

I'm trying to create an app which takes the user to the street address stored in my MySQL Database. The JSON is valid and I believe the URL is too.

What I believe is happening is the data is being lost and returned nil through optional binding. Or the URL is incorrect (I did check in a Playground to see if would return nil and the URL didn't)

I have been following this tutorial:
http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/
It is my first time connecting an app to a database.

I am relatively new to swift and trying to get the hang of it.

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My server is currently on a private network. But I know it won't affect the API

The data downloads but later on all variables say nil. App breaks in DetailViewController

ViewController

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, HomeModelProtocal  {

//Properties

var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
var selectedLocation : LocationModel = LocationModel()
@IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //set delegates and initialize homeModel

    self.listTableView.delegate = self
    self.listTableView.dataSource = self

    let homeModel = HomeModel()
    homeModel.delegate = self
    homeModel.downloadItems()

}

func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {

    feedItems = items
    self.listTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:    Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of feed items
    return feedItems.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:   NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Retrieve cell
    let cellIdentifier: String = "BasicCell"
    let myCell: UITableViewCell =   tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier)!
    // Get the location to be shown
    let item: LocationModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as!    LocationModel
    // Get references to labels of cell
    myCell.textLabel!.text = item.address

    return myCell
}

}
```

LocationModel

```
import Foundation

class LocationModel: NSObject {

//properties

var name: String?
var address: String?
var latitude: String?
var longitude: String?


//empty constructor

override init()
{

}

//construct with @name, @address, @latitude, and @longitude parameters

init(name: String, address: String, latitude: String, longitude: String) {

    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude

}


//prints object's current state

override var description: String {
    return "Name: \(name), Address: \(address), Latitude: \(latitude),   Longitude: \(longitude)"

}


}
```

HomeModel

```
 import Foundation

protocol HomeModelProtocal: class {
func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class HomeModel: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

//properties

weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocal!

var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

let urlPath: String = "http://dev.devmelb.com/service.php" //this will be changed to the path where service.php lives


func downloadItems() {

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var session: NSURLSession!
    let configuration =  NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()


    session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url)

    task.resume()

}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
    self.data.appendData(data);

}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask,   didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download data")
    }else {
        print("Data downloaded")
        print(LocationModel())
        print(error)
        self.parseJSON()
    }
}

    func parseJSON() {

        var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        do{
            jsonResult = try      NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, o .   ptions:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSMutableArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)

        }

        var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
        let locations: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
        {

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let location = LocationModel()
            print(location)

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let name = jsonElement["Name"] as? String,
                let address = jsonElement["Address"] as? String,
                let latitude = jsonElement["Latitude"] as? String,
                let longitude = jsonElement["Longitude"] as? String

            {


                location.name = name
                location.address = address
                location.latitude = latitude
                location.longitude = longitude

            }

            locations.addObject(location)


        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(locations)

        })


}
}
```

DetailViewController

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit

class DetailViewController : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var selectedLocation : LocationModel?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Create coordinates from location lat/long
    var poiCoodinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D();

    print(selectedLocation)
    print("\(LocationModel())")
    poiCoodinates.longitude = CDouble(self.selectedLocation!.longitude!)!
    poiCoodinates.latitude = CDouble(self.selectedLocation!.latitude!)!
    // Zoom to region
    let viewRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(poiCoodinates, 750, 750)
    self.mapView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)
    // Plot pin
    let pin: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    pin.coordinate = poiCoodinates
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(pin)

    //add title to the pin
    pin.title = selectedLocation!.name



}

}
```

Comment: In your console `Failed to download data` or  `Data downloaded` is printed or not?

Comment: That's a lot of code and you haven't told us where it goes wrong...

Comment: it says data downloaded. It breaks in DetailViewController

Comment: Lots of code... maybe, wanna try Alamofire with SwiftyJSON implementation? These library handle Http requests with JSON responses like a charm.

Comment: You are force unwrapping your `selectedLocation` Optional in `DetailViewController` but I can't see where it is populated, maybe you forgot to do it? This would explain why it's still nil when you try to use it.

Comment: dataTaskWithRequest is an async process and I don't see any completion handlers where you capture the returned data and append it where you want when you call that function.